# creating lambda expressions and apply on dataframe column in a loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `jsonDict` dictionary , which I get from json file , which tells me for which column which method to be executed and the `createMethodName` method in `Utilities` creates the code to be executed

```
 for col in columnList:
     if (col in df_output.columns):
         methodNameWithParam = Utilities.createMethodName(
             jsonDict["MethodMapper"][col] , dict1[col])                      
         df_output[col] =  df_input.apply(lambda x: methodNameWithParam , axis=1)
```

sample 
suppose the  `col = Coffee`

json method mapper list will give me the method name `Coffee_maker`, dict1[col] will give me the list of inputs to the method -- suppose the inputs are `[coffee,sugar,milk]`

so the `createMethodName` will give me a output as `Maker.Coffee_maker(x['coffee'],x['sugar'],x['milk'])`
 so this I will add in the lambda command -- Maker is the class where all the method is present.

```
methodNameWithParam  = Maker.Coffee_maker(x['coffee'],x['sugar'],x['milk'])
```

so for each iteration it becomes like

```
df_output[col] =  df_input.apply(
    lambda x: Maker.Coffee_maker(x['coffee'],x['sugar'],x['milk']), axis=1)
```

other examples

```
col = tea  
jsonDict["MethodMapper"][col] = tea_maker  
dict1[col] = tea,milk,sugar
methodNameWithParam  = Maker.tea_maker(x['tea'],x['milk'],x['sugar'])
```

But the issue I am getting , apply function is treating it as string , and the whole column is filled with `Maker.tea_maker(x['tea'],x['milk'],x['sugar'])` , its not executing the function

below the createMethodName function

```
class Uitilities     
 def createMethodName(methodname, inputlist):
        args= []
        for item in inputlist:
            args.append('x['+item+']')            
        argsString= ','.join(args)    
        return 'Maker.'+ methodname +'(' + argsString +')'
```

Comment: please add reference or post code of `Utilities` or `createMethodName`

Comment: added , its just simple string manipulation function

Comment: With this code, it is an expected result. `createMethodName` returns a string, which in turn is returned by the lambda. What is the expected behavior? Please add an example of input data and desired output

Comment: it should execute the function , which is coming as string